# Checking for cheating in a Sudoku puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I am writing a puzzling site at the moment, which will naturally include Sudoku. It struck me that there will be potential users that will try to cheat when solving puzzles. By cheat I mean that they will use software to solve the puzzle and then just copy the correct answer into my site.

If a user starts to enter the correct solution, is it possible to "know" that they could not possibly have deduced that that is the correct value for the cell, given the other values that are present at that moment?

Comment: They could use another platform / pen and paper to solve the puzzle (out of preference) and then just copy the full grid they solved themselves into your site. If you "force" them to use yours, you might be able to catch some fishiness by letting the site "cheat" itself (e.g. Multiple instances of 'The cell could be many values right now, but they entered 4 and let it stay till the end. Lucky guess or cheat' ). TLDR; I don't think theres a good way. If I may ask, are there prices attached or why do you want to prevent this, it doesn't sound like a forum

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I actually hadn't considered someone using pen and paper then filling in the grid, which is a very good point. In this case they may look like they are cheating but actually they are not. My site will be competitive in nature so speed of completion will be a factor. Many different puzzles (not just Sudoku) will be presented much like the rounds of a boxing match, so correctness and then speed will determine your round score against an opponent. I cheater may complete a grid super fast and it's that I would like to try and minimise.

Answer (score 10):

It follows from the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) that if a human brain can make a logical deduction in Sudoku, then a computer can make that exact same deduction.

Therefore, it's theoretically impossible to catch a cunning cheater.

The best you can hope for is to catch idiots, like people filling the grid by row by row, or in some other "that deduction wasn't possible yet" order, and even then you are going to get false positives from people that just don't like your sudoku app. (Trust me: no matter how shiny you make your app, there will be *many* of those.)

That's probably the only thing you can do, since lightning fast sudoku experts do exist, so speed alone isn't any indication of cheating.

Basically, the sensible option is to allow cheating, and kindly ask people not to.

Comment: Thank you Bass. I agree and thought it would basically be impossible. I'm thinking I will gather some heuristics (such as filling in the grid row by row) and make it clear on the site that doing this kind of thing will flag your entry as suspect. Too many suspect plays, will maybe get games passed for peer review. I log the moves so can replay your attempt at a grid in real time. there is fast and then there is inhumanly fast. Even an expert would not be able to complete a hard sudoku in say 20 seconds, but a grid could be completed that fast.

Comment: @ChromaticRanger, if I completed by paper and want to fill it in, I will be going either row by row or column by column. That would make me a cheat while I genuinely did it on paper and submitted. As others have already said, there is no easy way to solve for this. You just have to figure out by user behavior pattern. You cannot just use a single solve to determine if the user cheated.

Answer (score 6):

Checking for cheating is impossible. I myself have a [generator/solver online](http://kociemba.org/themen/sudoku/program.html) where you can solve a puzzle in verbose mode step by step with selected "human" methods  (hidden singles etc.). There are other programs (Sudoku Explainer, HoDoKu ...) which do the job for the standard 3x3 box size sudokus even better.

Comment: Thank you Herbert. Just took a quick look at your site. Took me back, as I was a Delphi developer many years ago. I'd actually forgotten about it until I saw it written on your site.

Answer (score 3):

Fighting against cheaters is hard, uncertain and time-consuming; you can hamper cheating, but you cannot stop it.

Thing about online game editors that are constantly struggling against cheaters. Think also about [CAPTCHA's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA): for the last 20 years, this has been a neverending arms race between websites and AI-robot developers.

---

Since you asked, here are some measures I can think of to hamper cheating:

- impose some rules, like using your online tools, in order to have more control over what is done and how it's done
- make your grid difficult to copy-paste into a solver: for example, the initial grid would be a background image that would necessitate [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to analyze (OCR tools are easy to find though)
- make your grid difficult to fill-in with a script, but easy to complete for a normal player
- measure the time and especially the regularity between the different steps (an automated tool will analyze the grid and fill it instantly; whereas a human will take some time between moves and, even if they are really quick, the time between two steps will never be constant)
- analyze the movements of the pointer (the mouse): it will show some hesitations if it is driven by a human, it may not move at all if a robot is solving your sudoku
- analyze, either in real-time or afterwards, the way the grid was solved. You need an automated solver that will know, at each step, what cell can reasonably be guessed. Add some heuristics: non-cheater moves will sometimes (<10%) look suspect (fortunate errors), whereas cheater moves will look suspect most of the time (>50%)
- do not show too early to a cheater that they have been identified. Take your punishment measures afterwards (e.g. nightly) after analyzing the way they played. Thus, they won't know exactly how you found out they were cheating and it will be harder for them to circumvent your anti-cheating measures.

---

In the end, there is no silver-bullet against cheaters. Every measure you take will be countered sooner or later **if that seems worthwhile** to the cheaters.

Now, let's elaborate on that "if that seems worthwhile". Ask yourself what is the incentive of a cheater. Instead of spending your energy on fighting against them, you can just deprive them from that incentive.

For example, maybe you have a ranking of best players? Is such a public ranking absolutely necessary? Remove this and problem gone.

You may reply that a ranking is also an incentive for the fair players. Strike a balance: you can make some rankings private (best personal times) or limited to a group of individuals that know each other (burden moved to them: let them identify and kick the cheaters themselves).

---

To conclude, let me repeat my introduction: fighting against cheaters is hard, uncertain and time-consuming; you can hamper cheating, but you cannot stop it. Think well where you want to spend your energy and do your best to keep having fun with your website

Obligatory hint (we are on PSE):

> fighting cheaters is no fun.

Comment: Thank you xhienne. Many excellent points here. I was planning on having rankings but like your idea of maybe not making them too public or only available to certain groups, like paid members for example ;-)

Comment: This is reminiscent of the old maxim to never mud-wrestle with a pig: you'll both get dirty, but the pig will enjoy it. Maybe it's not worth the effort to fight cheaters (cc @ChromaticRanger).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the simplest method is to **not** have the standard type of sudoku. For example, [this π-sudoku](https://threesixty360.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/pi-day-sudoku) will not be amenable to any standard solver. Sure, one can write a generalized sudoku solver, but how many people have one ready or can write a program to solve your non-standard sudoku? Of course, for you to create a non-standard sudoku you would probably have to write an efficient solver yourself, but that is much easier than trying to prevent cheating on standard sudokus online.

Comment: I like this angle of attack, and in fact since I wrote the original question back in February I have expanded my standard Sudoku offering to include grids where random sets of images/shapes take the place of the digits. this should hopefully foil the types of image processing apps that can be shown a standard Sudoku grid and solve them automatically as they will not recognize the characters. Things such as the PI doku type game would indeed take this to another level.

Comment: @ChromaticRanger: You're welcome. While using images would stop copying or auto-solving, it would not stop a person from manually translating then solving via computer then translating back, which would still be faster than manually solving. That's why generally the best way to prevent cheating is to make it impossible without significant intelligence. =)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different take in an attempt to slow down cheating:

Include a separate section where nothing qualifies as cheating.

Ideally, it's nearly identical to the "please don't cheat" section, to minimize the extra work. You keep rankings and everything else in place. You have the option to market this section of the site as a place people can go to test their auto-solvers and compete against each other.

Comment: Food for thought. Thanks Joel.